# removing write protection

Tags: computer-architecture

I tried to format my 32 GB SanDisk pendrive. But it showed me that " the disk is write protected" . I tried using CMD but it failed. I can't format it even using safe mode. Please help me to recover from this issue

Comment: This is a site about computer science. Unfortunately, your question is off-topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Making the supposition that you are using Windows and the drive doesn't have a physical switch, you can use diskpart to remove write-protection.
Open a command prompt (cmd) as administrator and type in the following, pressing enter after every line.

```
cmd> diskpart
diskpart> list disk
diskpart> select disk x
diskpart> attributes disk clear readonly
```

Obviously, omit the cmd> and diskpart> before each command, and replace x on the third command with the disk number from the second one.

P.S. This isn't the correct section for this question and your problem could have been resolved by a simple Google search

[Source](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/storage/how-erase-write-protected-usb-drive-or-sd-card-summary-3633096/)

Comment: this doesn't work for me. i was copying data from my macbook to a flash drive. it was failed in the middle of copying the data, after that I can not eject the flash drive. so i plugged it off. now it is on read-only state. searched on google but can't find any working method